# Suggesting a comment be deleted

Tags: support, questions, edits, comment-edits, editing-help

I don't have enough rep to delete comments yet, but I've seen several cases where someone comments "foo", and then comments "foo bar", and then "foo bar baz". I'd like to suggest that the first two comments be deleted; is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Comment deletion isn't a reputation privilege. Outside of flagging as described by [mmyers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82482/suggesting-a-comment-be-deleted/82483#82483) (which you get at 15), the only way comments can be deleted are by the owner of the comment, or a moderator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the flag button right below the upvote button to flag them as noise.

If there are many comments on the same answer that should be removed, just flag the answer itself for moderator attention.

Comment: I'm a bit miffed that I can't (as far as I can tell) specify *why* I'm flagging a comment. I flagged the first comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227503/clojure-reduce-reductions-and-infinte-lists/5227513#5227513 with the "intent" that it be removed because it is entirely superseded by his next comment, but the comment has remained and my flag weight has been lowered. Am I really wrong to have flagged this, or am I missing the way to clarify why I flagged it?

Comment: @amalloy: Probably someone dismissed the flag from the flag review page, where there is no context. Can you flag it again?

Comment: Okay, just did that. I'd have done it sooner, but SO seems not to be emailing me updates about my questions so I didn't see your comment. Time to look around on meta for information about that! :)

Comment: @amalloy: I see very much your point in your first comment here: it looks like your second flag was also dismissed as invalid before I could get to it. I guess in the case where a comment is good-quality but was double posted, it would be better to flag the answer and explain instead of flagging the comment.

Comment: I've flagged the answer now. Thanks for the suggestion; I never imagined there'd be a way to provide context only for *some* flags.